# Spring Data Pagination & AJAX

Tags: java, ajax, spring, pagination

I have the following Controller and I've just included pagination into my returned results

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/search/{person}", produces="application/json", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public Page<Person> findAllPersons(@PathVariable String person) {
    Page<Person> list = personRepo.findAll(new PageRequest(1, PAGE_SIZE));
    return list;
}
```

I'm now trying to figure out how to actually tab through these results - The search on the Person table has is it's own AJAX request, where as selecting "next" or "previous" on my UI tool can launch it's own GET

```
<a id="previous" href="onclick="setPageNumber(1)">
<a id="next" href="onclick="setPageNumber(2)">
function setPageNumber(num) { //relaunch request with page number value retrieved from previous or next}
```

Should I include a pageNumber as a `@PathVariable` like so:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/search/{person}/{pageNumber}", produces="application/json", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public Page<Person> findAllPersons(@PathVariable String person, @PathVariable int pageNumber) {
    Page<Person> list = personRepo.findAll(new PageRequest(pageNumber, PAGE_SIZE));
    return list;
}
```

or should setting the pageNumber be a completely separate controller method that somehow invokes `findAllPersons` with the pageNumber argument? I may be confusing myself here - any input is welcome thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For REST service I would put it to the parameters rather then to URI **page_start=X&page_size=Y**.

Answer (score 1):

I know this post isn't active for a long time but for anyone still looking for a way to use Spring pagination with Ajax, here are some possible solutions:

**1.** If your repository is an instance of `JpaRepository` (or more precisely `PagingAndSortingRepository`) then you can simply pass a `Pageable` to it:

```
@Controller
public class FooController {

    //...

    @GetMapping("/foo/list")
    public List<Foo> handleList(Pageable pageable) {
        return fooRepository.findAll(pageable);
    }

    //...
}
```

**2.** Instead of `Pageable`, you can also retrieve your pagination parameters as `@RequestParam` and create a `PageRequest` yourself. This approach might be useful if the project does not use Spring Data and JPA:

```
@Controller
public class FooController {

    //...

    @GetMapping("/foo/list")
    public List<Foo> handleList(
        @RequestParam(value = "size", required = false) Optional<Integer> pageSize,
        @RequestParam(value = "page", required = false) Optional<Integer> pageNumber,
        @RequestParam(value = "sort", required = false) Sort sort,
    ) {
        PageRequest pageable = new PageRequest(pageNumber.orElse(0), pageSize.orElse(10), sort);
        return fooRepository.customfindAll(pageable);
    }

    //...
}
```

(e.g. this repository above might be a class extending a JDBCRepository such as [this one](https://gist.github.com/criminy/1206700) )

And for the AJAX part of these two possible solutions, something like that can be used:

```
// ... handle pageNo, listSize etc.

var url = '/yourprj/foo/list?page=' + pageNo + '&size=' + listSize
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    contentType: "application/json",
    url: url,
    success: function(result) {
        // handle Foo list...
    }
});
```

**3.** Alternatively, if you are using Thymeleaf+Spring Data [there is a dialect](https://github.com/jpenren/thymeleaf-spring-data-dialect) to automatically add pagination.