# unable to send data of pagenumber and pagerows per page in ajax call in pagination jquery datatables

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring-boot, datatables, pagination

I am trying to load data from ajax call from the pagination on the html page but it is somehow not working.. not able to understand the problem

I have checked this link but ajax call is not working in my code i need to fetch the list of Company Registration and populate in the datatable with the implementation of pagination and while controlling the loading time of the page through pagination.(like the records are 5000 and it loads all together i need to fix server side pagination from ajax)

[Passing pageable (spring data) in post request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34889613/passing-pageable-spring-data-in-post-request)

```
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js">

<script type="text/javascript">
         $(document).ready(function(){
           $('#shortstorage').DataTable({
                    "pageLength": 5,
                    "processing": true
                    "serverSide": true
                      "ajax": {
                       "url": "/getcompany",
                     "type": "GET"
              }
                  }
                       } );
        });
   </script>
```

The call is make to the getcompanyy method in the  controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getcompanyy", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getCompanyy(Model model,HttpServletRequest request, @PageableDefault(value=10, page=0) Pageable pageable) {


        pageable = new PageRequest(pageable.getPageNumber(), pageSize, sort);

 Page<CompanyRegistration> compregPag = companyregister.findAll(pageable);
      List<CompanyRegistration> compreg = compregPag.getContent();
model.addAttribute("compreg",compreg);
return "admin/company";
```

Error

> **The code is loading all rows in data table without the pagination applied**

Comment: What is the expected result and what is actually happening? I don't think the question is clear enough...

Comment: @Lian i am updating the question. it is related to the ajax call make in jquery for server side pagination .. i need to fetch result on each page through ajax call

Comment: You said it is not working, but what is the error or behavior?

Comment: i am calling a method in it but the call is not working properly in ajax... I am sharing the method i called in it ...the data i require is i need in the datatable

Comment: @Lian the code is updated i am trying to requesting the method with the pagination parameters and call the updated list  from the db with the help of Pagable Object

Comment: @Lian it is like i have to paginate the data from server side

Comment: Check out this doc for datatable if you haven't: http://legacy.datatables.net/usage/server-side

Comment: Also, check out this answer which may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50579939/760331

Comment: Have you also checked out the sent parameters if you use server-side processing? https://datatables.net/manual/server-side You will have to read the `start`, `length`, (also `draw`) parameters and do your own pagination accordingly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215680/discussion-between-dhs-and-lian).

Answer (score 0):

You actually should return JSONObject,
take a look at this RestController, I think this is what you need:

https://github.com/solutionman/BaseProject/blob/master/src/main/java/com/project/base/controller/BaseProjectRestController.java

```
<table id="shortstorage" class="display">
</table>

$(document).ready( function () {
var table = $('#shortstorage').DataTable({
    ajax: '/base/getcompany',
    sAjaxDataProp: 'data',
    processing: true,
    serverSide: true,
    // "order": [[ 0, "asc" ]],
    columns: [
        { data: "id", title : 'id'},
        { data: "name", title: 'name' },
        { data: "shortname", title: 'shortname' }
    ]
})
```

});

```
    @RequestMapping(path = "/getcompany", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public Map< String, Object > getcompany(@RequestParam Map<String, String> data) {

    Map<String, Object> result = new HashMap<>();

    Integer draw = Integer.parseInt(data.get("draw"));

    ArrayList<Object> youObjectsSelected = new ArrayList<>(); // put your selected objects here
    int start = Integer.parseInt(data.get("start"));
    int length = Integer.parseInt(data.get("length"));
    for( int j = 0; j < 50; j++ ){
        Company company = new Company();
        company.setId(j);
        company.setName("someName");
        company.setShortname("shortName");
        youObjectsSelected.add(company);
    }
    ArrayList<Object> yourSObjectsForPage = new ArrayList<>(); // get only objects for displaying on page
    for( int k = start; k < start + length; k++ ){
        yourSObjectsForPage.add( youObjectsSelected.get(k) );
    }

    result.put("draw", draw);
    result.put("recordsTotal", 100);
    result.put("recordsFiltered", youObjectsSelected.size());
    result.put("data", yourSObjectsForPage);

    return result;
}
```

pagenumber and pagerows youll get from start and length (from data) :

int start = Integer.parseInt(data.get("start"));

int length = Integer.parseInt(data.get("length"));

and according to them select objects for rows from database, arrayList here just for example.

Comment: @Iom is ajax callback method will get only json from controller method ?

Comment: yes, only json.
In my case I send map, but it will be json in the end.

Comment: Can you update your answer with the ajax code ... my ajax code is not working

Comment: my last commit with this code works 
https://github.com/solutionman/BaseProject/commit/7e3ac74b8da1ae2b3566f19794e0b1be7b551c55

Comment: pagenumber and pagerows you'll get from data in your controller, select you query according to them, and send back only the part for current page.

Comment: How can i send the data ... how to fetch pagerows and number in javascript

Comment: this is amount of rows you should send back:
int length = Integer.parseInt(data.get("length")); 
you get this number, and select exactly that amount of record, then send int back. Check my last commit.
https://github.com/solutionman/BaseProject/commit/c9a0cb90f39c4d934c7b21a4a53c23e48ad994c2

Answer (score 0):

```
Page<CompanyRegistration> compregPag = companyregister.findAll(pageable);
//List<CompanyRegistration> compreg = compregPag.getContent();
model.addAttribute("compregPag",compregPag);
```

`compregPag` has content that is needed along with metadata. Use that as a model attribute.